Are tallitot which are rabbinically obligated put on before or after tefillin
The Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 25 rules you should put a Tallit on before tefillin, this is based on the principle of Tadir, mitzvot which are more common take precedence, generally. However, if one holds that a tallit made of material which is neither wool nor linen is only rabbinically obligated in Tzitzit, then which comes first, the Tallit or tefillin, as tefillin are a biblical law and this view holds that this Tallit is only a rabbinic law.

When I studied the laws of tefillin, it was emphasized to me not to pass over one mitzvah to do another, so depending on how you carry them, you maybe should have the practice of putting on whichever one you touch first.

Your link doesn't say anything about tadir or biblical obligations

There it says the reason is maalin bakodesh

The tallit is put on first even where it is only rabbinically obligated in tzitzit.
The Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 25:1 cited by the OP does indeed rule that one should put a tallit on before tefillin, in the cited passage the reason given is not the principle of "tadir", rather it is based on the principle of one is required to "ascend in holiness" - the relevant phrase from the Shulchan Aruch is - אחר שלבש טלית מצוייץ יניח תפילין שמעלין בקדש
The OP's question is addressed by the Mishnah Berurah in 25:1:1
(א) אחר שלבש וכו' - ואפילו אם הטלית אינו חייב אלא מדרבנן כגון שאולה אחר שלשים יום וכנ"ל בסימן י"ד וכל כה"ג ג"כ יש להקדימו לתפילין [ארה"ח]: [copied from Sefaria] https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.25.1?lang=bi&with=Advanced&lang2=en]
Translation of Mishnah Berurah from https://torah.org/learning/mishna-berura-s25/
MB 1: After donning etc. – Even if the tallit is obligated to have tzitzit only by rabbinical decree (e.g. a borrowed one after 30 days as mentioned above in siman 14, or any such case), he still should put it on before the tefillin (Artzot Hachaim).
